# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.op_def_registry' has no attribute 'register_op_list

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying out gpt2-simple by Max Woolfe (https://github.com/minimaxir/gpt-2-simple) and it seems like I can't get past importing gpt_2_simple. It keeps throwing an AttributeError. I've tried with both Python 2 & 3 and Tensorflow 1.14 & 1.15. Here's a screenshot of the full error:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB9HF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
!pip install requirements.txt #from the same above mentioned repo
!pip install tensorflow-addons   #will provide contrib support and remove the depreciation warning.
```

providing [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/7f28600dcdc0fee6f05259297dd06992/stack_61830033.ipynb) for reference.