# How to solve an Attribute Error -- no attribute 'register_op_list' in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to run this in jupyter and I get an AttributeError

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12,8)
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import pandas as pd
from keras_tqdm import TQDMNotebookCallback
```

I did a search and someone asked a similar question with no answer here: [AttributeError tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61426378/attributeerror-tensorflow)  (someone else asked similarly, here [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.op_def_registry' has no attribute 'register_op_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61830033/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-framework-op-def-registry-has-no-attr)).  I'm hoping to improve on the question by following a comment that was left on the question by giving my full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b19e750c758e> in <module>
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import tensorflow as tf
----> 6 import keras
      7 import pandas as pd
      8 from keras_tqdm import TQDMNotebookCallback

~/env/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py in <module>
      2 
      3 from . import utils
----> 4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications
      6 from . import backend

~/env/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/activations.py in <module>
      4 from . import backend as K
      5 from .utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
----> 6 from .engine import Layer
      7 
      8 

~/env/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/__init__.py in <module>
      6 from .topology import Layer
      7 from .topology import get_source_inputs
----> 8 from .training import Model

~/env/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in <module>
     23 from .. import metrics as metrics_module
     24 from ..utils.generic_utils import Progbar
---> 25 from .. import callbacks as cbks
     26 from ..legacy import interfaces
     27 

~/env/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py in <module>
     24 if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
     25     import tensorflow as tf
---> 26     from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
     27 
     28 

~/env/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py in <module>
     21 # Add projects here, they will show up under tf.contrib.
     22 from tensorflow.contrib import bayesflow
---> 23 from tensorflow.contrib import cloud
     24 from tensorflow.contrib import compiler
     25 from tensorflow.contrib import copy_graph

~/env/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/cloud/__init__.py in <module>
     20 
     21 # pylint: disable=line-too-long,wildcard-import
---> 22 from tensorflow.contrib.cloud.python.ops.bigquery_reader_ops import *
     23 # pylint: enable=line-too-long,wildcard-import
     24 

~/env/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/cloud/python/ops/bigquery_reader_ops.py in <module>
     19 from __future__ import print_function
     20 
---> 21 from tensorflow.contrib.cloud.python.ops import gen_bigquery_reader_ops
     22 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
     23 from tensorflow.python.ops import io_ops

~/env/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/cloud/python/ops/gen_bigquery_reader_ops.py in <module>
    191 
    192 
--> 193 _op_def_lib = _InitOpDefLibrary()

~/env/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/cloud/python/ops/gen_bigquery_reader_ops.py in _InitOpDefLibrary()
     94   op_list = _op_def_pb2.OpList()
     95   _text_format.Merge(_InitOpDefLibrary.op_list_ascii, op_list)
---> 96   _op_def_registry.register_op_list(op_list)
     97   op_def_lib = _op_def_library.OpDefLibrary()
     98   op_def_lib.add_op_list(op_list)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.op_def_registry' has no attribute 'register_op_list'
```

I'm using tensorflow 1.2.1.  I know it's old, but I'm trying to run some code on a github that was written three years ago.  It's been a pain trying to get all the versions correct to hopefully run the project.

Thanks!

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We can't fix code you didn't post.
Links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Prune posted my code that lead up to the traceback error

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34762 (there are a couple potential fixes near the bottom).  What version of python are you using? Note that the error happens during `import keras`, which is importing tensorflow modules. So, check that your versions of keras & tensorflow are compatible

Comment: Much better!  Thanks ...

Comment: @corvus I restarted my kernel like one of the people on that thread suggested and it worked.  When in doubt, restart. lol.  Now onto the next issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.6.0
!pip install tensorflow-addons
!pip install -q "tqdm>=4.36.1"

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
    
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12,8)
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as k
import pandas as pd
#from keras_tqdm import TQDMNotebookCallback
tqdm_callback = tfa.callbacks.TQDMProgressBar()
```

providing [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/cd2ec3dd007bd610b17d03a4251327ab/stack_66308078.ipynb) for reference
Reference:
https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/tqdm_progress_bar